# switch case declaration by a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement

```
   switch (wurf)
    {
        for(i=1;i<7;i++)
        {
               case [i]: d[i]++;break; //printf("%i: %i\n",i,d[i]);
        }
    }
```

Hello,
is there any possibility to declare the case by a loop? I tried out already 'i', but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to do somethink like [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)?

Comment: C is a static language! Why not use `if ( wurf == i ) ...` in the loop?

Comment: i just want to count the frequencys of wurf, so i was thinking about to save lines an write this instead of:
    case 1: ......
    case 2: .....
    case 3: .....
....

Comment: And how would a switch save lines compared of simply indexing into an array? Review your understanding of programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want a `switch` here. Perhaps you simply want

```
d[wurf]++;
```

If the bounds are important, you could check them with a simple `if`:

```
if(wurf >= 1 && wurf < 7)
    d[wurf]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that way won't work, but I don't see a reason why you couldn't just do:

```
if (1 <= wurf && wurf < 7)
    d[wurf]++;
```

Comment: "wurf" is a number, and should be designated to its  number (from 1 to 6)  within the array,  to count the frequency.

Comment: @hurm Isn't that what my code does?

Comment: sorry, absolutely! thank you very much. that solves the proplem as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (for-loop) inside to an (if-statement), that will allow you to specify the value of wulf.